# trying to listen to an event from the smart contract with websocket on nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to listen to an event from the smart contract with websocket on nodeJS and I'm getting this error.

“connection not open on send()”

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Sc0.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question and post your code as text (using Markdown or the `{}` symbol in editor) so that it's easier for answerers to copy and debug your code on their local machine.

Comment: See [Why should I not upload images of code in asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

Just try using another provider but let use be clear the websocket provider give only 10% more speed then normal provider